# Convert RFC3339 Format to Standard Date/Time

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime, rfc3339

Been searching through a lot of posts but I can't seem to grasp how to simply convert RFC3339 String Format from API Call to Standard Central Time Zone.  Here is what I am trying to do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
import pytz

#Initial Value from API
eventStart = "2023-10-11T06:10:35Z"

#Convert from String to Datetime
subDateTime = datetime.strptime(eventStart, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

#Setup Central Timezone
utc = pytz.utc
central = timezone('US/Central')

cstTime = central.localize(subDateTime)
print(cstTime)
```

`cstTime = 2023-10-11 06:10:35-05:00`

I am now trying to convert this to look like:   `10-11-2023 1:10`

I am sure there is a far more efficient way to do what I am trying above.  Thank you!

Comment: In the end you’re asking how to format a date?

Comment: Format or Convert.  Not sure what the most efficient way is.

Comment: Convert from… you have a date, you want it formatted, there’s a function for that. Is efficiency an actual concern here?

Comment: Yes formatting is what I am looking for.  the result I am looking for is posted above.

Comment: What prevents the formatting of the date?

Comment: Figured it out myself.  `cstTime.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %I:%M %p')`

Comment: Glad you worked it out. It might be instructive to figure out what prevented figuring it out yesterday, though 

Comment: note that `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'` ***does not*** parse the string to UTC datetime. You'd have to use `%z` instead of the literal Z. If you ignore this, the result will be wrong, depending on the time zone of the system you run this code on.

Comment: Great call out @FObersteiner I updated it to reflect the %z to make sure it keeps the UTC Offset before formatting.

Comment: there also might be some things you can simplify; e.g. use `fromisoformat` to parse the string (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418) for example), use the Python 3.9 built in [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) instead of pytz or a more recent version of the timezone identifiers ("US/Central" could be "America/Chicago"). Just have a look at the questions I linked.